# Delete zsh auto completion suggestion

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

When I use tab-completion in zsh, the shell suggests me files and I discover that I'm in the wrong directory. How can I just delete the suggestion instead of backspace'ing it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the undo command (`C-_` or `C-x u`) to cancel the effect of the last completion.

You can then press `C-q` or `M-q` to “suspend” the current command, enter `cd correct-directory` and resume your editing of that suspended command.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Hmm they all do not work, but I guess that is because I'm using iTerm on Mac, and the key combinations are actually triggering iTerm. For example, M-q quits iTerm :-/